clerk layout not showing up
I was trying to config clerk with my nextjs14 app , i've followed the docs but can't see the clerk layout also routes redirect to 404 page.
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}:{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <ClerkProvider>
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={kanit.variable}>{children}</body>
    </html>
    </ClerkProvider>
  );
}



Check if your Clerk Publishable key has changed. If you changed the domain and the sign-in component isn't rendering, verify these values in your Next.js .env file:
(check with clerk dashboard)
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=clerk-publishable-key
CLERK_SECRET_KEY=your-clerk-secret-key

Edit:

Also check your middleware. If your using authMiddleware change it with new clerkMiddleware. Check document for example code.
Try after clear next app cache

